# Delete terms from set that met a stated condition

Tags: list-manipulation

I hve a set `S` consisting of four terms.

```
S = {a b, c d, c e a, a b c, b c d}
```

I need a code to delete terms within the set `S` when the following condition is met: delete any terms containing a two-element term also in the set.

For example

$a\,b \subset a\,b\,c,\ c\,d \subset b\,c\,d$

then we delete `a b c` and `b c d`, reducing `S` to `{a b,c d,c e a}`

Please help.

Comment: But `a b` contains a two-element term also in the set (`a b`).  Why didn't you delete *that*?  Also:  never use an upper-case letter to denote anything in *Mathematica* as it may conflict with the naming conventions in the language.

Comment: Are the a, b, c, etc. supposed to commute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what the Mathematica form of the set is. I will assume that the set elements are just symbols:

```
DeleteDuplicates[
    {ab,cd,cea,abc,bcd},
    StringContainsQ[SymbolName[#2],SymbolName[#1]]&
]
```

> {ab, cd, cea}

**Update to new form of $S$**

```
DeleteDuplicates[
    {a b, c d, c e a, a b c, b c d},
    Denominator[#2/#1]==1&
]
```

> {a b, c d, a c e}

This assumes that shorter symbols are ordered before longer symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Build a graph firstly

```
g = RelationGraph[StringContainsQ[##] && UnsameQ[##] &, ToString /@ S]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The sink vertex is what you are after

```
GraphComputation`SinkVertexList[g]
```

> {a c e, c d, a b}

Answer (score 1):

This

```
S = {a b, c d, c e a, a b c, b c d};
sets = List @@ S; 
supersets[s_] := Select[sets, Intersection[#, s] == s && Length[#] > 2 &];
tobedeleted = Flatten[Map[supersets, Select[sets, Length[#] == 2 &]], 1];
DeleteCases[sets, Alternatives @@ tobedeleted]
```

gives you `{a b, c d, a c e}`

Test this carefully before you depend on it